# how to add a new application module in wireless host in omnet ++

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

My question is like this: I create a custom host in omnet ++ with a simple module called my_app [see image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN6m1.jpg). I want this module to behave like an application that generates messages and also get notified when a message is received from the lower layers. when I add hosts in the network and run the simulation I get the following errors. [see image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdH3F.jpg)

This is my c++ files (my_app.cc and my_app.h ) `

```
#ifndef __MYAPP_MY_APP_H_
#define __MYAPP_MY_APP_H_

#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;

/**
 * TODO - Generated class
 */
class My_app : public cSimpleModule
{
  int type;
  protected:
    virtual void initialize();
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg);
};

#endif`
```

my_app.cc `

```
#include "my_app.h"

Define_Module(My_app);

void My_app::initialize()
{
    this->type=par("type");
    if (this->type==1){  // 1 for source
        cMessage *msg=new cMessage("welcome");
        send(msg,"out");
    }
}

void My_app::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    if (msg->arrivedOn("My_app_In"))
    {
        if (this->type==2){  // 2 for sink
            delete(msg);
        }
        else
        {
            cMessage *msg=new cMessage("welcome");
            send(msg,"My_app_Out");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        error("Incorrect gate");
    }
}
```

`
and this is the ned files. my_app.ned

```
`package myapp.simulations;

//
// TODO auto-generated module
//
simple My_app
{
        parameters:
        int type;
    gates:
        input My_app_In;
        output My_app_Out;
}`
```

host.ned

```
`package myapp.simulations;
import inet.applications.contract.IUDPApp;
import inet.applications.pingapp.PingApp;
import inet.common.lifecycle.NodeStatus;
import inet.common.packet.PcapRecorder;
import inet.linklayer.contract.IExternalNic;
import inet.linklayer.contract.ITunNic;
import inet.linklayer.contract.IWiredNic;
import inet.linklayer.contract.IWirelessNic;
import inet.linklayer.loopback.LoopbackInterface;
import inet.mobility.contract.IMobility;
import inet.networklayer.contract.IRoutingTable;
import inet.networklayer.common.InterfaceTable;
import inet.networklayer.contract.INetworkLayer;
import inet.power.contract.IEnergyStorage;
import inet.power.contract.IEnergyGenerator;
import inet.applications.contract.IUDPApp;
import inet.transportlayer.contract.IUDP;

module Host
{
    parameters:
        @display("bgb=486,475");
        @networkNode;
        @labels(node,ethernet-node,wireless-node);
        bool hasStatus = default(false);
        int numExtInterfaces = default(0);
        int numRadios = default(0);               // the number of radios in the router. by default no wireless
        int numPcapRecorders = default(0); // no of PcapRecorders.
        int numTunInterfaces = default(0);

        string mobilityType = default(numRadios > 0 ? "StationaryMobility" : "");
        string networkLayerType = default("IPv4NetworkLayer");
        string routingTableType = default("IPv4RoutingTable");
        bool forwarding = default(true);
        bool multicastForwarding = default(false);
        string energyStorageType = default("");
        string energyGeneratorType = default("");
        routingTable.forwarding = forwarding;
        routingTable.multicastForwarding = multicastForwarding;   // for IPv4, IPv6, Generic
        *.interfaceTableModule = default(absPath(".interfaceTable"));
        *.routingTableModule = default(routingTableType != "" ? absPath(".routingTable") : "");
        *.energySourceModule = default(energyStorageType != "" ? absPath(".energyStorage") : "");
        *.mobilityModule = default(mobilityType != "" ? absPath(".mobility") : "");
        string udpType = default(firstAvailableOrEmpty("UDP"));
        @display("i=block/circle");
    gates:
        input radioIn[numRadios] @directIn;
    submodules:
        My_app: My_app {
            @display("p=271,150");
        }
        status: NodeStatus if hasStatus {
            @display("p=50,50");
        }
        energyStorage: <energyStorageType> like IEnergyStorage if energyStorageType != "" {
            parameters:
                @display("p=50,100;i=block/plug;is=s");
        }
        energyGenerator: <energyGeneratorType> like IEnergyGenerator if energyGeneratorType != "" {
            parameters:
                @display("p=50,150;i=block/plug;is=s");
        }
        // optional mobility module. Required only if wireless cards are present
        mobility: <mobilityType> like IMobility if mobilityType != "" {
            parameters:
                @display("p=53,200");
        }
        // network layer
        networkLayer: <networkLayerType> like INetworkLayer {
            parameters:
                @display("p=271,281;q=queue");
        }
        // routing table
        routingTable: <routingTableType> like IRoutingTable if routingTableType != "" {
            parameters:
                @display("p=53,250;is=s");
        }
        // linklayer
        interfaceTable: InterfaceTable {
            parameters:
                @display("p=53,300;is=s");
        }
        pcapRecorder[numPcapRecorders]: PcapRecorder {
            @display("p=53,350,r,10");
        }
        lo0: LoopbackInterface {
            @display("p=145,406");
        }
        wlan[numRadios]: <default("Ieee80211Nic")> like IWirelessNic {
            parameters:
                @display("p=407,406,row,60;q=queue");
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
        networkLayer.transportOut++ --> My_app.My_app_In;
        networkLayer.transportIn++ <-- My_app.My_app_Out;

        // connections to network outside
        networkLayer.ifOut++ --> lo0.upperLayerIn;
        lo0.upperLayerOut --> networkLayer.ifIn++;

        for i=0..sizeof(radioIn)-1 {
            radioIn[i] --> { @display("m=s"); } --> wlan[i].radioIn;
            wlan[i].upperLayerOut --> networkLayer.ifIn++;
            wlan[i].upperLayerIn <-- networkLayer.ifOut++;
        }
}
`
```

please help me.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell, but my guess is that you have to re-generate the Makefile every time you add some new classes the project. Also make sure, that you add the .cc and .h files into a 'source' folder. (Usually it is 'src' by default in OMNeT++ projects). It is also possible that you are using a separate project that is using the INET project by linking to it and you somehow start the INET project only and not your own project.

Comment: Hi Sir Thanks for your response. I'm still beginner to omnet. Yes my project is linked to INET. Can You please explain how to start INET project and my own project in the same time?